# Print SQL Query when user searches from admin product grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, admin-panel, product-grid

I am using Magento 2.3.4

Can we print a SQL query when product search from admin product grid?

I can print sql queries in our custom or product collection in frontend using

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

but I want to print the SQL query in the admin product grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento cli command: `bin/magento dev:query-log:enable`

This will enable logging for all sql queries. It's not a perfect solution, but you will be possible to find needed sql.

Magento docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/logging.html#to-enable-database-logging

Comment: it is not print SQL query,it just show json fields and their values

Comment: No, please check var/debug/db.log in your project. There you can see all sql queries which were executed after db query logging enabling.

Comment: It may need to flush cache bin/magento cache:flush after enabling/disabling query log.